# How to hide the navigation bar in for certain page ? flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to hide the navigation bar for some pages in flutter
for example, [image]  how to remove it ? since in this page there is no line about the bottomNavigationBar .

this is my code :

```
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  final PageController _pageController = PageController();
  GlobalKey<CurvedNavigationBarState> _bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();
```

---

```
Scaffold(
  body: PageView(
      controller: _pageController,
      children: <Widget>[
        Home(),
        ProfilePage(),
      ],
      onPageChanged: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
        });
      }),
  bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
    key: _bottomNavigationKey,
    index: _selectedIndex,
    height: 67.0,
    items: const [
      Icon(Icons.home),
      Icon(Icons.person),
    ],
    color: Colors.grey.shade100,
    buttonBackgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(153, 177, 202, 1),
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
    animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    onTap: (index) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedIndex = index;
        //_pageController.jumpToPage(index);
      });
    },
    letIndexChange: (index) => true,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Visibility Widget and set `visible` to be `index != 2`
or you could try to make the `bottomNavigationBar:` conditional by writing `bottomNavigationBar: index != 2 ? CurvedNavigationBar(...) : null,`

**EDIT:**
If your page is a child inside the top page you have to use a Callback to tell the parent that you want it to hide the navbar.
then in the callback you could just set a bool `hidden` that, when true, hides the navbar.

Comment: it's not working since this page ( edit page ) requested from the profile page (inside it ), but thank you .

Comment: Can you be more specific ? , if there's no problem can you show me how .

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/flutter-widget-communication

Look at Step(4) of this Article and replace the Function(int) with a Function(bool)

Comment: this doesn't help